# How to deploy Hyperledger Fabric in "Embeded System"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am testing an embeded board which CPU is RK3399 to deploy hyperledger fabric network.

Steps:

1. install Docker:
   version:

```
Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89
```

2. install Docker Compose:

```
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896
docker-py version: 3.7.3
CPython version: 3.6.8
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

3. clone 'fabric-sample' project:

```
git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git
```

4. type in command './start.sh' in basic-network, and returns:

```
ERROR: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
```

I typed command: 'uname -a', and returns:

```
Linux NanoPC-T4 4.4.167 #1 SMP Fri Jul 12 17:32:47 CST 2019 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

How Can I deploy HF in this board? If there are any images which I can 'pull'.

If I need to make Hyperledger Fabric Docker by myself, is there any guide I can follow?

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error trying to deploy chaincode to the test-network sample:
`Failed to pull hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv:2.3: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries`

I am trying this out on an Apple M1 laptop and even though I had defined amd64 as the docker default platform
`export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64` I still would get the error.

What solved my problems was doing the pull of the image
`docker pull amd64/hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv:2.3`
After that I was able to start up the test-network and deploy the chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

I found a docker hub contains `aarch64` HF image,

the url is : `https://hub.docker.com/u/ptunstad`

I'll test later.